# What is the difference between deep and shallow history? How are they indicated? in uml

Tags: uml, history, modeling

What is the difference between deep and shallow history? How are they indicated?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Well, it's obvious that this is for StateMachines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`deep-history` is similar to `shallow-history` except it represents the most recent leaf-substate of the composite state.

`shallow-history` is shown as a circled letter H.

`deep-history` is shown as a circled H*.

Source: [Quantum leaps](https://www.state-machine.com/qm/sm_hist.html)